# eBay API EAN for Variation Listing

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am using eBay API to revise a product on eBay that has variations of `Size` and `Colour`.

I have used the [documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/revisefixedpriceitem.html) to configure my XML file.

However the request returns below error message:

> 21919420: For multiple-variation listings, GTIN values are specified
>   at the variation level. Please remove the GTIN value from the listing
>   level and provide a GTIN value for each variation within the listing.

My Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReviseFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials><eBayAuthToken>'.USERTOKEN.'</eBayAuthToken></RequesterCredentials>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
<Item>
<ItemID>'.$param['itemID'].'</ItemID>'.$xmlpriceandquantity.'
<Title>'.$itemTitle.'</Title>
<ProductListingDetails> 
<BrandMPN> 
<Brand> Navdari </Brand>
<MPN> 2016 </MPN>
</BrandMPN>
<EAN> ".$param['EAN']." </EAN>
</ProductListingDetails> 
<Variations>
<Variation>
<SKU>".$stockdetail['id'].$stockdetail['itemref']."</SKU>
<StartPrice>".$stockdetail['price']."</StartPrice>
<Quantity>".$stockdetail['qty']."</Quantity>
<VariationProductListingDetails> <EAN>".$param['EAN']."</EAN> </VariationProductListingDetails>
<VariationSpecifics>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Size</Name>
<Value>".$stockdetail['size']."</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Color</Name>
<Value>".$stockdetail['colour']."</Value>
</NameValueList>
</VariationSpecifics>

</Variation>
</Variations>
</Item>
</ReviseFixedPriceItemRequest>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is referring to the fact that you have specified the *EAN* **twice** in your request. Once in *ProductListingDetails* and a second time in the *VariationProductListingDetails*. If the item is a multi-variation listing you do not need the *EAN* that is in *ProductListingDetails*. Edit this element so that the *EAN* is removed.

```
<ProductListingDetails> 
    <BrandMPN> 
        <Brand>Navdari</Brand>
        <MPN>2016</MPN>
    </BrandMPN>
</ProductListingDetails>
```

Comment: The product is multi variation listing.  With removing above part this is the error message i get: Attribute System Version 11114. RequestErrorEnter a value in EAN and try again.EAN is missing a value. Enter a value and try again.21919401 Warning Enter a value in EAN and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your EAN value on the parent, each individual item / sku will have a unique EAN so it will need setting for each variation instead

Comment: That is correct as i already set that on my code <VariationProductListingDetails> <EAN>".$param['EAN']."</EAN> </VariationProductListingDetails> However this still provides me error. I have used the XML layout as EBAY provided.

Comment: What value is contained in $param['EAN']? I know that EANs have to be 13 digits long and it's possible to get errors if you are passing less than that.

Comment: Hello, what i meant was that you are passing EAN higher up (line 13)  with this:  <EAN> ".$param['EAN']." </EAN>   under the brand section.  This needs removing as you pass EAN only for the children and not the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Its a glitch in the system
Yes of course. Here are the steps that we can follow: 1. Under the 'Add item specifics' section, you will see the section with the '/////' symbol. 2. Untick the details under this item specific 2. Click on the 'Remove' button beside the item specific 3. Add the item specific again after revising the listing, a pop-up will appear, while adding, untick all the items again with the '//////' symbols. 4. Once the item specific has been added, you will see the items with '/////' ticked again 5. You will need to untick the options again 6. Click on the 'Continue' button and at the bottom part of the page.
The other workaround is to revise the listing through the Bulk Edit And Relist (BEAR TOOL). By doing that, the member will not receive the error message and they will